# 2 activity android

Tags: java, android, animation, android-intent, rotation

I have 2 activity and when i go to A from B and then i press "back" it creates antoher activity but i don't return to the same

Comment: I don't think saving/restoring the rotation will help. It should be resuming the activity with the rotation you had previously, the "lag" is probably from the animation updating with a large time step. I would cancel the animation in onPause() and then restart it in onResume().

Answer (score 0):

When you go activity A to activity B. Just use `startActivity(yourIntent)` without `finish()`.  Like-

```
Intent goNext = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(goNext );
```

Then when you go back from activity B to activity A, just use `finish()` method on  your activity B. Like -

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    finish();
}
```

**OR**

You can use [startActivityForResult()](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example)

Comment: It works, but how can I prevent the lag of the View that is on rotating?

Comment: If you use intent, then you should use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity() method. Do you need to get data from activity B to A?

Comment: Yes in this case I need to get data from B to A and the particular thing is that the View that is on rotating lags when i return to A

Comment: In this case, you should use startActivityResult() instead of using startActivity(). Its different to use. It allows us to go an activity from current activity and get a data or result from that activity to current activity. Try to understand how to use onActivityResult(), setResult(), for startActivityForResult() from the link i provided on answer. If this answer helps you . then tick the answer and vote up.

Comment: Yes, I know about startActivityResult() and I think that I should use this method instead of startActivity().
But the bigger problem is that the View lags when i return to the previous activity (A). I can send you apk-debug so you can understand this and watch by your eyes

Comment: yes, sure. you can send me the apk. also you can add me on skype - agm.tazim .